# I am having trouble on understanding how to prove compactness for a specific set in a Metric space

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, metric-spaces

Question: Let $(x_n) \rightarrow x_0$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ and $C = \{x_0, x_1, x_2, ...\}$.

(a)Prove that C is closed.

(b)Prove that C is compact in terms of open covers

proof:
(a)Since $C$ is the set that consists of only the sequence $(x_n)$, we know that any subsequence also converges to $x_0$. Using Theorem 3.2.5 from Abbott, we know that $x_0$ cannot be a limit point of C. Hence, $C$ has no limit points. Therefore, $C$ is closed.

I am having trouble proving that C is compact. I've tried $C \subseteq \bigcup U_i$ where $i \in I$. We want to show $\bigcup_{k=1}^n U_k$ where $U_k \subseteq U_i$

Comment: *"we know that $x_0$ cannot be a limit point of $C$"* <-- This doesn't sound right. As the limit of a sequence of elements of $C$, $x_0$ by definition is a limit point of $C$.

Comment: I agree that you may have to review the terminology of a limit point for part a, although the initial ideas are on the right track. Here is the idea for part b:

$C$ has infinitely many points. Yet, the points $x_n$ for $n \ge 1$ approach $x_0$. So, we can try to cover the infinite tail of the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ by a single open set, and then only use finitely many more open sets to cover the remaining points that are in the head of the sequence

Comment: (the head of the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a casual term which means the first few finitely many terms of the sequence, while the tail refers to the remaining infinitely many terms of the sequence afterward)

Comment: Theorem 3.2.5 from Abbot states, $x$ is a limit point of $C$ iff $x = \lim a_n$ for some sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $C$ satsifying $a_n \neq x \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. But, every sequence in $C$ converges to a point in $C$, so $x_0$ cannot be a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $C$. Then there's some $j$ s.t. $x_0 \in U_j$. Since $U_j$ is open, there's some $r >0$ with $B(x_0, r) \subset U_j.$

Now because $(x_n)$ converges to $x_0$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there's some $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. for all $n > N$ we have $|x_n - x_0| < \epsilon$. In particular, this is true for $\epsilon = r.$ Thus $x_n \in B(x_0, r)$ for all $n \ge N$ meaning $U_j$ contains $x_0$ and all the elements of $C$ past $N$ like $x_N, x_{N+1}, x_{N+2}, \ldots$

Up to $N$, there are only finite number of elements, that is, $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{N-1}$. Each one of these belongs to at least one $U_i$. To cover all these elements, we need at most $N - 1$ open sets ($U_i$s).

Thus we have shown the finite subcover $\{U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_{n - 1}, U_j\}$ covers $C$ and so $C$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

One useful way to say that $x_n\to x_0$ in a metric space is that for any open $U$ such that $x_0\in U,$ the set $\{n\in\Bbb N: x_n\not\in U\}$ is finite.

Let $G$ be an open cover of $C.$ Take $U\in G$ with $x_0\in U.$ Let $A=\{n\in\Bbb N: x_n\not\in U\}.$

Now the set $B=\{x_n:x_n\not\in U\}$ is finite because $A$ is finite and $\forall x\,(x\in B\iff \exists n\in A\,(x=x_n)).$ So take a finite set $H=\{g_x:x\in B\}\subset G$ such that $x\in g_x$ for each $x\in B.$

Now $\{U\}\cup H$ is a finite subset of $G$ and it covers $C$ because $\cup H\supset B=C\setminus U.$